# SSB4 Reflect Damage Multiplier Cap

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In SSB4, most reflect moves, such as Pit's Guardian Orbitars, reflect projectiles and put a multiplier on the damage of the reflected projectile. Assuming that two players are able to perfectly time the reflects, a projectile could keep getting reflected back and forth between the two. Is there a cap on the amount of damage that the projectile can do or does it scale infinitely (or cause buffer overflow)?

Comment: [This seems relevant!](https://youtu.be/2EP4wgLsPPs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit to how much damage is reflectable. In SSB4 if the damage is more than the maximum damage that is reflectable by the reflect move the projectile will ignore the reflector and hit the user normally.

[You can see here](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Reflect) for a list of reflect moves and the max damage that is reflectable by each. Note that the list is incomplete for some moves, but it's likely that the max damage will be similar.

For the most part the reflect moves are in the 50-100 range for max damage.